# Location on screen corresponding to keycode

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, keycode, keyup

I'm trying to create code that allows me to press a button on the keyboard and have a corresponding circle appear on the screen. The position would be relevant to the key pressed. For example, the letter a would be different from b. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script>

        $(document).bind('keyup',function(event){
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            var theObjectCoorespondingToTheKeyTheyPressed = _.where(keyPlacementMap,{keycode:keyCode});
            theObjectCoorespondingToTheKeyTheyPressed = theObjectCoorespondingToTheKeyTheyPressed[0];
            console.log(event);
        })

    </script>
```

I'll change the variable names eventually; it's just useful for me to have them named as such for now.

I'm also using jquery and underscore, and I have an array that holds all the keycodes, as well as a randomized x and y variable.

Comment: what's your question then?

Comment: _"I'll change the variable names eventually"_ - Or you could change it now to something like `correspondingObject` so that we don't have to scroll right to see all of your code. (Surely the "ToTheKeyTheyPressed" part is implied by the fact that it's a local variable inside a key event handler.)

Comment: consider adding a `data-` attribute to each element which is equal the `keycode` that it represents. It would then be just a matter of highlighting the element received in the `keyup` event

Answer (score 0):

Add x/y positions to your keymap. Two separate classes is the best way to accomplish this because it allows you style the selected and unselected keys anyway you like (including hide and show them)

I did a small QWERTY sample here

http://jsbin.com/ivuseh/2

CodeView:

http://jsbin.com/ivuseh/2/edit

The '.button' class can style pressed keys however you like bigger, colorized, visible. In the example I'm redrawing all buttons on each keypress which isn't necessary. It pretty easy to separate those functions to optimize.